# Android : How to Launch My activity instead of Browser 

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I am new to android, I am designing an application in which i want to use broadcast receivers. By using this i want to launch my application when somebody clicks on browser (Default android browser). If anybody had done this, please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is bad practice in my opinion. As a user, when I launch the browser I expect the browser to open, and nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

You can't intercept launches of the main browser, however, you can make your application handle intents for viewing URLs. To do this add something like this to AndroidManifest.xml in the section of your activity:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an intent-filter for some url (using http scheme). By this way, if user browse on an identified url, your app will be launched instead of the webpage.

more details here: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ifs
and here: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

Regards, Patrick